# Uploading to a DICOM Server in Background

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have a dicom server to which I upload images, and I am wondering if there is a way to keep my iOS app in the background while uploading is in progress.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background), only http and https protocols are supported for 
background uploading:

- Only HTTP and HTTPS protocols are supported (no custom protocols).

Is there a workaround for background transfer with a custom protocol?